# How to create a subnavigation in MVC5 with Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Creating a simple navigation for the different views of a MVC5 page is fairly easy. Declaring view, hooking up appropriate controllers. But how can I create a subnavigation / submenu that is always visible as long as the routes are within the range of a controller?

Example illustration:

```
HOME       >BLOG<      USERS
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ADD  ENTRY        |
>MANAGE ENTRIES<  |           CONTENT VIEW OF "MANAGE ENTRIES"
                  |
                  |
                  |
                  |
```

while the Home controller may only look like this:

```
>HOME<       BLOG      USERS
----------------------------------------------------------------------

           CONTENT VIEW OF "HOME"



 .
```

My first approach was using sections (along with RenderSection on the layout page), but since I have to declare the section everytime on each view, this seems to be very redundant.

Comment: you can create Nested _Layouts, though there are certain restrictions, but still they can help you with lot of less code writing

Answer (score 0):

What about the classic solution, where the menu section can be put in the master _Layout and the content of the particular view in the RenderBody Section.

As regards RenderSection, since you set the parameter *required* to *false* there is no need to declare the section in all views.